Linux Mint doesn't recognize HDMI
After switching to Linux Mint 21.3, I noticed that the system does not recognize the HDMI cable when it is connected to a TV.
Even when I open the monitor settings window, it doesn't show any options other than the notebook screen.

The image below shows other information about the system in use:

How could this problem be solved?

What does xrandr show?

After trying to connect HDMI several times, xrandr shows: VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis); HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm; 1920x1080 60.00*+ 50.00 59.54 24.00 23.98

That looks like only HDMI is connected, but nothing else? Did you try adding a monitor with xrandr?
